# How do I get the variables in a column from java and sql?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, arraylist

So say a column is named Names I want to get a ArrayList of every variable inside of this column. Example:

```
Names
Test
Test1
Test3
River
World
Etc
```

I want to get all of that into an array list. Thanks for the help!

Comment: First, you'd correctly identify the database containing the table.  (Hint:  tag your question with the database you are really using.)

Comment: He's got both MySQL and Oracle tags.  For getting names into a list: ORM, DbUtils (from Apache), lots of typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not giving much information in your question (e.g. what is the *table* you'd like to query), so here's a somewhat generic solution:

```
 public List<String> retrieveAllColumnValues(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

    String query = "SELECT Names FROM MyTable";
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            values.add(rs.getString("Names"));
        }
        rs.close();
    }
    return values;
}
```

Getting data from the database through JDBC roughly consist of the following parts:

- You have a [`Connection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) which you use for creating SQL [`Statement`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)
- When you execute the `Statement`, you get a [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), which contains the values returned by your query
- You iterate through the `ResultSet` and do what you need to with the values

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted :)